# Is this the correct way to use useSWR with getServerSideProps in next js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, frontend, swr

This is the code sandbox example of how I'm using SWR with getServerSideProps: https://codesandbox.io/s/useswr-with-getserversideprops-nextjs-9u1gp?file=/containers/PostContainer/index.js

Here is github repo for same: [repo](https://github.com/shubham2270/useSWR-with-serverSideProps-nextjs)

What I want to achieve is on the `post/[post]` page the meta tags will be dynamic coming from the backend & will be users specific that's why I'm using `getServerSideProps` instead of `getStaticProps`, the above code is working fine but when I see the terminal on clicking a post it's calling the API 3 times & when I again click the same post API is being called 2 times is this normal behaviour?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit, what is being called 3 and 2 times? Also, if you are using `getServerSideProps` then why do you even need `swr` here? All the data will be fetched on the server anyway, why fetch it again on the client? (Yes, there is fallback, but anyway it's redundant)

Comment: While providing a link to the code is fine, your question should be self-contained and preferably not rely on external resources to be answered. Please add the relevant code to the question.

Comment: You should see only 2 API calls being made, once on the server from inside `getServerSideProps`, and then on the client from `useSWR`. Any additional requests you might see on the client-side are probably related to SWR [automatic revalidation](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/revalidation) that is enabled by default.